# Repository and DAO in same time

Tags: spring, jpa, stack-overflow

i were using DAO in my spring project and all were fine then i insert a jqgrid that need spring-data-jpa (repository) and now when i'm trying to use my DAO's i have a java.lang.StackOverflowError ; could it be a dependencies problem?

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.eclipse.persistence.logging.DefaultSessionLog.getLevel(DefaultSessionLog.java:88)
    org.eclipse.persistence.logging.DefaultSessionLog.shouldLog(DefaultSessionLog.java:108)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.shouldLog(AbstractSession.java:4040)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4085)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.logDebugMessage(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5527)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerExistingObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3884)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerExistingObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3854)
    org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.buildUnitofWorkCloneForPartObject(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:95)
    org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.buildCloneForPartObject(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:69)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.cloneAttribute(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:76)
    org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.buildClone(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:251)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.populateAttributesForClone(ObjectBuilder.java:3497)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.populateAndRegisterObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3650)
....

Comment: You probably have some circular logic.

Comment: There is a foreign key defined in the entity class and when you insert the record, it cann't handle the relationship correctly. Check the foreign key reference of your entity